# Find the minimum.

Tags: permutations

If $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{100}$ and $y_1, y_2, ..., y_{100}$ are permutations of the set of numbers $1,2,3,...100$, what is the minimum value of $x_1y_1+x_2y_2+...x_{100}y_{100}$?

I'm pretty sure the minimum is when $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{100} = 1,2,...,100$ and $y_1, y_2, ..., y_{100}= 100,99,...,1$. However, I can't figure out the sum of the product $1 \cdot 100 + 2 \cdot 99 + ... + 100 \cdot 1$. Could someone tell me if my work is correct and how to calculate such sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chebyshev rearrangement inequality will confirm your answer as the right one.

If you want to calculate the required sum, use known formulas: $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{100} i(101-i)= 101\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{100} i  - \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{100} i^2$$

This is then equal to:
$$
\frac{101 \times 100 \times 101}{2}  - \frac{100 \times 101 \times 201}{6} = 166650
$$

Using the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} i  = \frac {n(n+1)}2$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Comment: Ahh, so that's what the inequality was! I forgot what the Chebyshev inequality was. Thank you for showing me how to sum up the series! :)

Comment: @user406996 You are welcome!